# onclick property in img tag in .append from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to add some tags in a  from the js code

I found an interesting function in jquery: append x)

I got this in my .js:

```
function goClick(target) {
}

function clickChapDiv(event) {
     $(event.currentTarget.parentNode).append("<span> <img src=\"../images/popUp.png\" /> <span class=\"textPopUp\"> <span class=\"notePopUp\">B-</span> <span class=\"titlePopUp\"> 3-JE TESTES </span> <img src=\"../images/minigo.png\" class=\"buttonPopUp\" onclick=\"goClick(this);\" /> </span>");
}
```

But this isn't working, if i remove the onclick=\"goClick(this);\", it's working but there is no event on the  (normal...)

Is someone has an idea of my problem ? cause i saw some code on internet with onclick event in the .append and their code was working...

Thanks for your futur answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code below. it is not fully closed which may be causing your problem

```
<span> 
  <img src=\"../images/popUp.png\" /> 
  <span class=\"textPopUp\">
    <span class=\"notePopUp\">B-</span> 
    <span class=\"titlePopUp\"> 3-JE TESTES </span>
    <img src=\"../images/minigo.png\" class=\"buttonPopUp\" onclick=\"goClick(this);\" />         
  </span>
```

Add the extra span at the end.

Also you need to bind the click event when the element is added to the DOM.

Instead you want to use `.live`. [See here](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$(".buttonPopUp").live("click", function(){
  goClick(this);
})
```

Comment: furthermore, i dont understand how that was working without the missing </span> oO